# Assembly Programming and Interrupt Handling

Tags: assembly, interrupt

I'm writing a program in assembly using MIPS architecture for a class, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab an input character by a user and store it in a register to process.

The program would open a console, output a message, the user can then input a character and then this determines what is supposed to happen next in the program.

Like I said, I'm having trouble figuring out how to grab the character so that I can act upon it in the program.

thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with interrupt handling? Your question is a bit vague...

Comment: I was of the understanding that the program would be in an infinite loop and then when a user pressed a key this would cause an interrupt, changing the registers and then said interrupt would have to be handled and control returned to the spot in the loop that it occurred.  

Sorry my question is vague.  I'm not sure how to further clarify.

thanks

Comment: I guess my question is using a MIPS architecture, what registers do I need to modify so that input from the keyboard is recognized, stored, and processed. 

Hopefully that is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good starting point: [MIPS Quick Tutorial](http://logos.cs.uic.edu/366/notes/MIPS%20Quick%20Tutorial.htm)

Here is a snippet from the tutorial

```
li  $v0, 5          # load appropriate system call code into register $v0;
                    # code for reading integer is 5
syscall           # call operating system to perform operation
sw  $v0, int_value  # value read from keyboard returned in register $v0;
                     # store this in desired location
```

You won't be working directly with interrupts with any assembly you are writing in user-space.

Answer (score 0):

Write exception code. Interrupt (Exception) service routine starts at 0x80000180 (on QtSpim, PCSpim)
Read the keyboard register. Data is at 0xFFFF0004. Grab the char. Then return from exception.

Or, you can poll keyboard status at 0xFFFF0000. When ready bit is on, read the data.

jjc.hydrus.net/cs61c/handouts/interrupts2.pdf